# Filtering Slicers

Tags: powerbi, ssas

I have a multidimensional cube visualized in Power BI

Imagine a fact table which has a total sales amount which is filtered using slicers. Problem is when you choose some slicer's options the chart's value showing sales amount by country falls to zero.

In other words I have some junky choices in my slicer which i want to throw away and clean them. Any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: Please include more detail. What junky choices ? Refer [ask]

Comment: see it this way i have a chart(sales amount by city) ok? i create a slicer for city so when i choose for example 'alabama' the chart falls to zero and if i use a card to show me the sales amount it says 'Blank' so technicaly i need to pull 'alabama' out of my slicer cause its up to no use it wont show me any valuable data but i dont know how i can remove it from slicer

Comment: show us your data, show us your current design, then we will be able to help you out. you can edit your question add screenshots and so on.

Comment: Tried, filtering your slicer visual? Was introduced a couple of versions ago so make sure you have the latest PowerBI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cleaning up slicers is very useful and pretty easy to do, thankfully.

To give you an example of how, and why you may do this, follow this hastily put together example.;

You have a client, Fruit Land USA that sells fruit on a grand scale. They send you data about the fruits that they sell, you clean it up and sent it back as reports.
Jackson Appleman from Fruit Land USA emails you and tells you that the reports you send out are fine, but he has a special love for Apples, for some mysterious unknown reason that isn't evident by his name.

What do?

You can throw down a slicer onto the report as you normally would, but now you see apples, oranges, pears, peaches, and bananas in your slicer. You don't want this.
So what you can do is click your slicer and drag your fruit column into the "visual filters" pane on the right, and deselect everything except for apples. Congrats, Jackson will now only be able to see data related to apples for this slicer.
But oh no, Jackson Appleman has navigated to page two. He sees data for bananas, pears, peaches, apples, and oranges. He nearly vomits at the sight of these non-appley fruits.
What do?

You can forgo the slicer filter, and follow that same path, except keep scrolling down and drag that fruit column into the "report level filters" and deselect everything except for Jackson's succulent apples. 
But now John has a craving for that yellow apple data. He's tired of seeing the plain, old, cliche red apples, and the bitter green apples.
What do?
You can click the tab that says 'Basic Filtering' on your fruit column inside of the filter (whether it be on the slicer or report) and change that over to advanced filtering. Depending on your data, you can choose 'is not' and hide those boring apples. Bam, Jackson Appleman, who is becoming a real jerk at this point, no longer sees the apples he isn't specifically looking for.

I could go on and on about Jackson Appleman and his tedious requests, but I think you get the point. I hope this helped you. Otherwise, I hope learning about Jackson Appleman was good enough.

Comment: Thank you it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

(To add some imagery to my comment)

Make sure you have used the latest version of Power BI as some versions ago (I believe it was May) they introduced filtering of your slicer visual. See the image for an example.

[image: filter slicer]